# where is the rainbow bar in this colorpicker and why can't i just click a color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, color-picker

I'm trying to use http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/ to build a color picker and am having some difficulties. My code:

```
<div style="width: 50px; height: 50px; border: 1px solid black"></div>

<script>
$('div').ColorPicker({
    onShow: function (colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
        return false;
    },
    onHide: function (colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
        return false;
    },
    onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
         $('div').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
    }
});
</script>
```

The JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zu5uv650/3/

In the JS Fiddle the rainbow bar on the right (that http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/ shows) isn't showing up for me. Any ideas?

Also, it seems I have to click and drag for the colorpicker to work. ie. I can't just click and have it select the color I clicked on. Any ideas?

Comment: As far as I can see, you are only missing a few background files.

Comment: How do I remedy that with this colorpicker? Do I hack jsfiddle.net and upload to jsfiddle.net's server? I would have thought that CSS looking for relatively pathed images would look for images relatively pathed to the CSS - not to the HTML. Is that an incorrect assumption?

Comment: The background images are set in another CSS file (layout.css)

Answer (score 1):

The `layout.css` file was missing in your work. I added it to the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zu5uv650/5/), and also rewrote the code to this:

#### HTML

```
<div id="colorSelector">
    <div style="background-color: #0000ff"></div>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$('#colorSelector').ColorPicker({
    onShow: function (colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
        return false;
    },
    onHide: function (colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
        return false;
    },
    onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
         $('#colorSelector div').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
    }
});
```

You still can't just click and pick a color, you have to drag it first, this is a limitation of the plugin itself, it should be fixed by the developers.

Comment: It still seems that layout.css wasn't intended to be included by end users by the devs since their example on the implement tab at http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/#implement only has css/colorpicker.css and js/colorpicker.js being included..

Comment: Well yes, but if understand this correctly, you have to provide your own design to the colorpicker, in this case you just simply copy the example.